# Unable to add rdp user using azure custom script extension

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform

I am facing an issue using microsoft custom script extension
i am unable to add user in remote desktop group using powershell command script.

My powershell script is below

````
$uservalue= "domainname/$env:UserNAME"

$group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/Remote Desktop Users,group"

$group.Add("WinNT://$uservalue")```

I was able to run the script inside the server manually but unable to add user in rdp group using microsoft custom script extension.
````

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to add rdp user using azure custom script extension

Make sure that the execution policy on the target server allows running **PowerShell** scripts.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine
```

Verify the script execution using the below commands.

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\sample\Log.txt" 
Write-Output "Custom Script execution started"
```

I have followed the below steps to add the user to **Remote Desktop Group** using **Custom Script Extension**

1. Uploaded **PowerShell Script** to **Azure Storage Account**.
2. Added the **PowerShell Script** from **Storage Account** to **Custom Script Extensions**.

**PowerShell Script**

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine
    Start-Transcript -Path "C:\Temp\ScriptLog.txt"
    Write-Output "Script execution started"
    $uservalue= "windowsserver/venkat"
    $group [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/Remote Desktop Users,group"
    $group.Add("WinNT://$uservalue")
    Write-Host "User $userAccount added to the Remote Desktop Users group."
    Write-Output "Script execution completed"
    Stop-Transcript
```

Once the above script is run, the user is successfully added to the **Remote Desktop group** as shown below.

Custom Script Extension Result.

[image]

The user is added to **Remote Desktop Group**.

[image]

Comment: i am unable to add username in the rdp which is env:username

Comment: when i run the script i was able to add computername but not username in the script this is from the script log file Transcript started, output file is C:\Temp\ScriptLog.txt
Script execution started
User domain/DEV-machine-111$ added to the Remote Desktop Users group.
Script execution completed

Comment: i want to pass username in the script not hardcoded username as you did can you please help me

Comment: Kindly share the extension script result if you ran the above script to find the issue. I was able to add the user to the RDP group without any grammatical errors.